# simplexml_load_file not working to read rss feed at www.thetechjournal.com

Tags: wordpress, rss, simplexml

When I try to read the rss feed at www.thetechjournal.com I get nothing. They use wordpress to generate the rss, so I assume it has something to do with that.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://feeds.thetechjournal.com/TheTechJournal';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($rss);
?>
```

UPDATE: The offending XML is attached as an image.

[image: offending XLM markup is in this image]

Comment: You can use this service to check whether the feed is valid (although it doesn't seem to be loading right for me at the moment) http://validator.w3.org/feed/

Answer (score 1):

Their feed has errors. Check it with this:

```
$url = 'http://feeds.thetechjournal.com/TheTechJournal';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($url);
if ($sxe === false) {
echo "Failed loading XML\n";
foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    echo "\t", $error->message;
}
}
print_r($rss);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, any form of PHP xml parsing is going to fail because it's getting back invalid CDATA

Comment: Hi wunderdojo, thank you kindly for the code. When I ran your code I get the following error message: "Failed loading XML Start tag expected, '<' not found" I looked for the missing character in the feed source, but could not find it. Could you explain this error message.

Comment: That feed isn't passing valid XML markup. I just hacked around at a few things to try and clean it before processing but no go. Here's where I was going with it:  

$url = "http://feeds.thetechjournal.com/TheTechJournal";
$file = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, stream_context_create(array('http' =>array('user_agent' => 'php' ))));
$xml=html_entity_decode($file, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo $dom->saveXml();

Comment: The invalid XML lines are located between 951 to 954, see image I just posted in the initial message. If I remove those 4 lines the XML is valid. But I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: By the way the feed error code you supplied always returns "Failed loading XML Start tag expected, '<' not found". So I suspect it doesn't work on all linux servers.

Answer (score 0):

I am from TTJ team. When I do run this Validator it shows fine, but as we have some iFrame is marks those issue. And sometime if some post have any weird char that what makes it invalid. Please point out to me any exact issue that we could look into. I do appreciate your concern.

[http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.thetechjournal.com%2FTheTechJournal](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://feeds.thetechjournal.com/TheTechJournal)